# How do I split a .txt file into a multidimensional array or dictionary in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary, parsing

The body of my txt file that I need to parse in in this format:

```
Name: LittleX
Package: com.ioscreatix.littlex
Description: iPhone X features for Non-X devices on iOS 11, and iPad Dock and PiP for All iOS 11 Devices on iOS 11

Name: InteliX
Package: com.ioscreatix.intelix
Description: Grouped Notifications for iOS 11
```

I want my array to have each package separately in an array listed by their name values with a dictionary for  description and package. How would I accomplish this?

This is the code i have so far:

```
var unfilteredPackagesArray = [String]()
    var secondFilteredPackagesArray = [String]()
    var finalFilteredPackagesArray = [String]()

if let startWordsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Packages", withExtension: "") {
            if let startWords = try? String(contentsOf: startWordsURL) {
                unfilteredPackagesArray = startWords.components(separatedBy: "\n\n")

                print(unfilteredPackagesArray)
                secondFilteredPackagesArray = startWords.components(separatedBy: "\n")


                finalFilteredPackagesArray = startWords.components(separatedBy: ":")

                print(secondFilteredPackagesArray)
```

What is the best way to do this? Create Package objects and make an array of them?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The problem is that I am getting this txt file from entering http://repo.packix.com/Packages.bz2. That gives me a bzip2 package that I still dont know how to open with swift and in that is a txt file. Sadly I cannot get a json from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, go ahead!

Yes, I think you should create a `Package` struct and then generate an `array of Package(s)`.

Here's the code.

### 1. Define the Package struct

```
struct Package {
    let name: String
    let package: String
    let description: String
}
```

### 2. Load the file

```
guard
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Packages", withExtension: "txt"),
    let content = try? String(contentsOf: url)
else { fatalError() }
```

### 3. Extract the lines

```
let lines = content
    .components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    .compactMap { $0.components(separatedBy: ": ").last }
```

### 4. Extract the 3 arrays

```
let nameLines = lines.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 3 == 0 }.map { $0.element }
let packageLines = lines.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 3 == 1 }.map { $0.element }
let descriptionLines = lines.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 3 == 2 }.map { $0.element }
```

### 5. Generate an array of Package(s)

```
let packages = zip(nameLines, zip(packageLines, descriptionLines))
    .map { (name: $0, package: $1.0, description: $1.1) }
    .map (Package.init)
```

### 6. Test

```
print(packages)

[
    Package(name: "LittleX",
            package: "com.ioscreatix.littlex",
            description: "iPhone X features for Non-X devices on iOS 11, and iPad Dock and PiP for All iOS 11 Devices on iOS 11"
    ),
    Package(name: "InteliX",
            package: "com.ioscreatix.intelix",
            description: "Grouped Notifications for iOS 11"
    )
]
```

Comment: What about using stride instead of the 3 arrays to zip (twice) later? That would avoid also 3 filters. Additional question: The last `compactMap()` to remove the ":" first part, is it better here, or to remove in the custom `init()` method of Package?

Comment: @Larme stride is a good alternative to this functional programming approach.

Comment: @Larme About your second question, can you please elaborate further?

Comment: By doing `.compactMap { $0.components(separatedBy: ": ").last }`, you are iterating once again the whole array, while this could be done in the `Package.init()`.

Comment: @Larme Now I see your point. Your solution would be faster than mine indeed. But I am not sure about having an initializer that discard part of the passed parameters.

Comment: Not faster, but you assume that there won't be another ":" in the text, while you might want to drop the first (and not keep only the last). I wasn't about making a faster one, but a more readable one maybe with a Factory method? Quickly tested on my MBP : https://pastebin.com/gusYyJAi